# Numbering of groups in select (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a following example - table with name, department and country. I need to create a select statement that lists all records and assigns unique number to each group of department and country (column Group in the example):

```
Name   Department   Country   Group
====== ============ ========= =====
James  HR           UK        1
John   HR           UK        1
Alice  Finance      UK        2
Bob    Finance      DE        3
Frank  Finance      DE        3
```

I thought of some select with analytic function but I found only `row_number() over (partition by department, country)` which numbers records inside the group and not groups themselves. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table, approximately, for how many departments and countries? This could orient to one or another solution depending on their occurences.

Comment: I can have many rows, tens of thousands.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT  t.*, q.grp
FROM    (
        SELECT  q.*, rownum AS grp
        FROM    (
                SELECT  DISTINCT department, country
                FROM    mytable
                ORDER BY
                        department, country
                ) q
        ) q
JOIN    mytable t
ON      t.department = q.department
        AND t.country = q.country
```

or

```
SELECT  t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY department desc, country desc) AS grp
FROM    mytable
```

Comment: The dense_rank() solution is exactly what I searched for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit clunky, but you could do a a sub query ( or in this case using the with clause ) on the table to get the distinct department per country then get the rownum from that.

```
set echo on

DROP TABLE TESTXX

 DROP TABLE TESTXX succeeded.
CREATE
    TABLE TESTXX
    (
      NAME       VARCHAR2 ( 10 )
    , DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2 ( 15 )
    , COUNTRY    VARCHAR2 ( 2 )
    ) 

CREATE  succeeded.
INSERT INTO TESTXX VALUES
    ( 'James', 'HR', 'UK'
    ) 

1 rows inserted
INSERT INTO TESTXX VALUES
    ( 'John', 'HR', 'UK'
    ) 

1 rows inserted
INSERT INTO TESTXX VALUES
    ( 'Alice', 'FI', 'UK'
    ) 

1 rows inserted
INSERT INTO TESTXX VALUES
    ( 'Bob', 'FI', 'DE'
    ) 

1 rows inserted
INSERT INTO TESTXX VALUES
    ( 'Frank', 'FI', 'DE'
    ) 

1 rows inserted
```

.

```
WITH
    X AS
    (SELECT
        XX.*
      , ROWNUM R
      FROM
        (SELECT
            DEPARTMENT
          , COUNTRY
          FROM
            TESTXX
          GROUP BY
            COUNTRY
          , DEPARTMENT
          ORDER BY
            COUNTRY DESC
          , DEPARTMENT DESC
        ) XX
    )
  SELECT
      T.*
    , X.R
    FROM
      TESTXX T
    INNER JOIN X
    ON
      T.DEPARTMENT  = X.DEPARTMENT
      AND T.COUNTRY = X.COUNTRY
    ORDER BY
      T.COUNTRY DESC
    , T.DEPARTMENT DESC

NAME       DEPARTMENT      COUNTRY R                      
---------- --------------- ------- ---------------------- 
James      HR              UK      1                      
John       HR              UK      1                      
Alice      FI              UK      2                      
Bob        FI              DE      3                      
Frank      FI              DE      3                      

5 rows selected
```

Comment: Quassnoi dense_rank suggestion is a better solution.